# MPandroidchart some dot's color doesn't change

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm making scatter chart that if value over specific value,

the dot's color is changed.

I wrote codes like these.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
{  
       float y = (float) (Math.random()*0.2+0.1);
       value1.add(new Entry(i, y));

        if(y>=0.2f)
        {
            colors.add(getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_red));
        }
        else
            colors.add(getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_skyblue));
       }
}
```

And the result is below.

[image]

As you can see, there is a line.

Upper side's color should be red, lower side's color should be blue.

And you can see the square that below the graph.

for example,

the number of the squares is same as the number of circles, 9

but only one circle is blue.

I think there is no problem in my codes.

But clearly there is a problem.

Please let me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two sets for the points above and below the reference and assign colors to the two sets.

```java
ArrayList<Entry> aboveLevel = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Entry> belowLevel = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    float y = (float) (Math.random()*0.2+0.1);
    if (y>=0.2f) {
       aboveLevel.add(new Entry(i, y));
    } else {
       belowLevel.add(new Entry(i, y));
    }
}

ScatterDataSet set1 = new ScatterDataSet(aboveLevel, "Above");
set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[0]);

ScatterDataSet set2 = new ScatterDataSet(belowLevel, "Below");
set2.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[1]);

ArrayList<IScatterDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(set1); // add the data sets
dataSets.add(set2);

// create a data object with the data sets
ScatterData data = new ScatterData(dataSets);

chart.setData(data);
```

Comment: Wow! What a brilliant idea! Thanks for sharing your excellent idea! It is working! Thanks again!